# How are you keeping your WPF resources organized on large projects?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources

On even the smallest WPF examples and prototypes I've been doing, **the `<Windows.Resources>` begins to bloat fast**. Putting it back into `app.xaml` puts it all out of my Windows and UserControls but it is **hard to organize** (the Visual Studio "XAML folding" feature is of no help since you just have a page full of the word "Style...").

In addition, I'm struggling to come upon an easy-to-remember and organized way of **naming my styles**. The best way I have found it just to be long and descriptive, so I get things like this: BottomMainLeftScrollViewerStyle, etc. But this has its limits and soon gets confusing as well. I decided to use **camelCase for style names** to easily spot them in pages and pages of XAML.

**What are your strategies** for preventing WPF resources from becoming unwieldy?

```
<Window.Resources>

    <local:CutOffConverter x:Key="AgeConverter" Cutoff="30"/>

    <Style TargetType="Grid" x:Key="customerGridMainStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint=".5,.5">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="#888"/>
                    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="#ccc"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="mainStackPanelStyle">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ScrollViewer" x:Key="mainScrollViewerStyle">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="250"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="mainListBoxStyle">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
    </Style>


    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="customers"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type local:Customer}"
                        MethodName="GetAllCustomers"/>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Customer}">
        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Style="{StaticResource customerGridMainStyle}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="First Name" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding FirstName}" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Last Name" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding LastName}" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="Age" Margin="5"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Age" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Age}" Margin="5"/>
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Age, Converter={StaticResource AgeConverter}}">
                <DataTrigger.Value>true</DataTrigger.Value>
                <Setter TargetName="Age" Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/> 
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use separate `ResourceDictionary`s and merge them into the appropriate levels in your visual tree as needed.

```
<App ...>
    <App.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ListBoxResources.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="ComboBoxResources.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="LabelResources.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="TextBoxResources.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- if you have local resources, place them here.
                (as noted by Mark Synowiec in the comments)
             -->
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </App.Resources>
</App>
```

Comment: Just to add a quick note, if you're also needing to add other resources to the above, place them after the MergedDictionaries section... ie:
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                ...
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- local resources go here -->
        </ResourceDictionary>

Pretty simple, but not immediately obvious.

Comment: "...merge them into the appropriate levels in your visual tree...": What does this mean? I understand what listing resource files in the MergedDictionaries collection in App.xaml is. Is mergig into "appropriate levels" something more sophisticated?